# Gulp error when running: Gulp-sass no longer has a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-sass

I am getting the following error message when trying to run my gulp script.

`
gulp-sass no longer has a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the "sass" and "node-sass" packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
`

Versions being used are:

"devDependencies": {
"gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
"sass": "^1.63.6"
}

npm: 9.5.1
node: 18.16.0
gulp: CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1

Edit: Upgrading gulp is not an option since it isn't my code. It is NetSuite code and upgrading would be a large task since there are so many scripts.

To fix the issue between gulp and node breaking I have:
"overrides": {
"graceful-fs": "^4.2.11"
},
and I install with: npm i --ignore-scripts

I have tried doing as it suggests as well as the other option I have seen in another thread. Neither of which have helped and I am very stuck on what to do as I don't have a great understanding of gulp and don't know where to look.
[Error description suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iocbt.png)
[Alternative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1pAz.png)

---- Update -----

I have answered my question below and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, I worked it out!

The problem was I was placing that code in my gulpfile.js which is different from where sass was being used; it was being used 3 tasks deeper which made it difficult to find.

I needed to place the declaration there.

@Alexander's answer above I believe is the better solution which is to upgrade to gulp v4, however as I responded in that question upgrading wasn't an option since it isn't my code base.

Answer (score 0):

Works just perfectly on gulp 4, you should migrate to gulp 4, not a big task. Gulp 3 is hopelessly outdated imho. Otherwise try to downgrade your `gulp-sass` module to the version that uses `node-sass`.

Comment: I agree that would be the best approach, the main problem is it isn't my code base it's NetSuite created code. I will attempt to downgrade gulp-sass hopefully that works.

Comment: @PanagiotisFatouros if it works don't forget to accept my answer (the checkbox). you could also upvote it (the arrow up) if you find it helpful

Comment: Unfortunately, this stackoverflow account is new, so I still need more credit. This solution didn't work because I am (unfortunately) needing to develop on Windows at the moment which node-sass doesn't support. Thank you for your advice, though. It helped get to the root of the issue!